# Full calendar not showing inside bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, fullcalendar

I want to load a modal dialog using bootstrap modal. Inside of it i want to show a fullcalendar (the jquery one) with some events on it. I have created my modal, and put inside the full calendar. But Full calendar won't show when modal appears. But it shows when after the modal has appeared i press on either next or previous buttons. But then no event appears on the calendar.[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mzAEj/1/)
and code

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div id="calendar"></div>
                </div>
            </div>            
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    header:{
        left:'prev',
        center:'title',
        right:'next'
    },
    events:'/eventsfeed/',
    defaultView:'agendaDay'
});
```

That also make events not to appear on calendar. This is what my /eventsfeed is returning

```
[{"url": "/calendar/entry/223", "start": "2013-12-04T17:00:00Z", "end": "2013-10-04T16:45:00Z", "description": "a body", "title": "Title entry"}]
```

I use fullcalendar in different pages of my project and events and everything render normally.

How can i make it load when modal appears

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should try this :

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
   $("#calendar").fullCalendar('render');
});
```

Here is your fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mzAEj/2/

Here is the documentation : http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/render/

---

### FullCalender V4

In reading the doc you can read that this command is deprecated,

You've to call calendar.render() is order to have the same behaviour

**[Extract of code](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-es6) :**

```
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ dayGridPlugin ]
  });

  calendar.render();
```

**[Doc source](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/render)**

Comment: This saved my day...Own you a beer ;)

Comment: @Apostolos: is it possible to create a modal when the user clicks on the event on fullcalendar?

Comment: @RobertoFlores I am not sure it will be easy. Boostrap documentation stated that modal inside a modal isn't supported and must be done programmatically. So I am guessing it can be done in a way but you should implemented yourself.

Comment: @Apostolos Sorry, I feel I did not made myself clear and the following is my question I am asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37557185/use-bootstrap-modal-on-fullcalendar-js?noredirect=1#comment62607024_37557185

Comment: @Kamlesh I've updated the answer with the part for V4, hope it helps ...

Comment: @PimentoWeb Thank you but could you please tell me how to re-render a Version 4 calendar after doing some stuffs or functionality in javascript. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the this approach.

After the loading of .modal trigger the MONTH, DAY or WEEK button of the Calendar.

```
$('.modal').focus(function(){
  $('.fc-month-button').trigger('click');
});
```